# Store form in one file, access it with another HTML file?

Tags: html, forms

I want to create a (lengthy) form that I will display on multiple pages of my website.

So, I want to create one HTML file and write the code for the form (let's call this form.html).

Then, in another HTML file (let's call this homepage.html), I want to access the form I coded in form.html.

Is this possible? Seems simple, but I'm struggling to find anything too helpful on Google. 
What line(s) of code do I need for this? Do I need to store the form in a function and call the function...or do I simply include form.html in homepage.html?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you use any server side languages like PHP? Or does it all need to be plain HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**jsBin example using jQuery**](http://jsbin.com/myIndex_html/2/edit)

You can always use AJAX with **jQuery** and you're done in one line of code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="content"></div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('#content').load('form.html #myNiceForm'); // This one :)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And on form.html page you have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <form id="myNiceForm">
    <textarea></textarea>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

The above will include the `#myNiceForm` from *form.html* into `#content` of *index.html*

---

Now that your elements are dynamically loaded into the *index* document, if you want to get some event you might want to use the jQuery's `.on()` method for event delegation like i.e:

<sup>in index.html page</sup>

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){
  // "static parent""event"  "dynamic element"
   $("#content").on("click", "#myNiceForm", function(event){
      alert(event.type);
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: @user2996892 you're welcome! Edited a bit my code I was using an unnecessary DIV element :) Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

The implementation depends largely on the technology in use here. 
Server side frameworks like .Net and Ruby etc support user controls that will let you include shared components on a page.

If you are looking at a pure JavaScript/html version I would recommend pulling in a snippet of html (contents of form.html) and insert it via ajax into the other form.

Comment: Thanks -- using bootstrap. I'll look into ajax if you think it'll work here!